# using a java 9 compiled library in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, or-tools

I am trying to use the or-tools java library from google in Kotlin, problem is that when it's time to compile, it gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/ortools/constraintsolver/RoutingModel has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

So, is it possible to use this library in Kotlin or should i rewrite the software in Java?

Comment: If you want to use a Java 9-compiled library, then you need to run it on a JDK9 JVM. That's no different for Kotlin than for Java. Just run it with a JDK9 JVM and the error will disappear.

Comment: Wow thank you, the error did disappear, now I get some other errors but they seem to be because of my lack of experience with the installation procedure of or-tools.